# In ArcGIS 10.6, how do I build a model to intersect iteratively?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.6, intersect, iteration

This is my first time building a model from scratch, so let me know if I've omitted anything in describing this question.

I have a geodatabase that contains shapefiles (polygons) of watersheds. I need to intersect each polygon with a shapefile (polygons) of land use. I can get the following to work, but only for one file at a time.

[image]

But I'm not sure I've created a model that will properly loop through all the watersheds in the geodatabase (see below). I used a for loop, but I'm not sure I used it properly. I also need them to be exported as their original name, but in a different geodatabase. Is this how an iterative intersect model would work?

[image]

Comment: Simple intersect will do unless your watersheds stored in different feature classes

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're intersecting the same land use polygon feature class to all watersheds I would try something a bit like this:

[image]

The in-line substitution in the output should get the path to your result gdb and create a feature class that inherit the name of the feature class in your input gdb.

Comment: The inline variable substitution should be something unique like "Inter_%Name%" Using "%Name%" may overwrite  your input watershed layer.

Also, if there are other feature classes in the GDB, try putting "Water" or something unique at the beginning of all the watershed feature classes. That way, when you use Iterate Feature Classes you can add Water* as a wildcard to only include feature classes that start with that word; instead of using all feature classes in a GDB.